# How to set date/time from unix timestamp under bash

Tags: bash, datetime, unix-timestamp, busybox

How to set date/time from unix timestamp under bash

```
root@M501 />date
Thu Jan  1 00:10:49 UTC 1970
root@M501 />date +%s
652
root@M501 />date +%s -s "`date +%s`"
date: invalid date `662'
```

as You can see date +%s -s "2323123" do not work :/

[SOLVED] ..under bash i can use

```
date +%s -s "@`date +%s`"
```

or

```
date -s @1361529589
```

Thanks!

Question #2 How to achieve this under busybox?

```
root@M501 />date -s @1361529589
date: invalid date `@1361529589'
```

maybe there is way like

```
echo '1361529589' > /dev/unix_time_stamp_or_whatever ? :)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to prefix the number with the `@` symbol so that the `date` command knows that it represents the number of [seconds since the Epoch](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html#Seconds-since-the-Epoch). Try this:

```
date +%s -s @`date +%s`
```

Comment: it works! ...but only under bash - as asked. How to achive this under busybox? ..updating my question

Answer (score 3):

Use something like this:

```
date -s @435456646
```